# SvgImage.FromResources returns null

Tags: .net-core, devexpress

Since I upgraded from Framework 4.7.2 to .Net5 the following code does not load an image from resources.

```
var assembly = typeof(MyAppWindowsFormsModule).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
var resourceName = $"MyApp.Module.Win.Images.MyPicture.svg";
var theImage = SvgImage.FromResources(resourceName, assembly); // returns null
```

The image is embedded in the project's Images folder with Copy If Newer.

I expect I should try converting [this demo project](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/winforms-dashboard-custom-items-extension/tree/58aa55e8109f69974e1cc4cc71688c5e343a3b6e) to c# to try and reproduce the problem.

Comment: This user resolved the problem themselves; I don't know if their solution is applicable to your problem: https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t948678/fluentform-cannot-load-svg-with-svgimage-fromresources.  Also consider opening a support ticket with DevExpress (if that's an option for you).

Comment: Thanks I am already using Embedded. I don't want to bother DX unless I am sure it is a bug ( too many questions already)

Answer (score 0):

The following works instead

var filename = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Images",$"{name}.svg");
theImage = SvgImage.FromFile(filename);